# Is special hardware needed to install a Blu-ray player on a PC?

Tags: optical-drive, blu-ray

I heard on the TechSupportGuy forums that you need a special hardware or chipset to watch Blu-ray videos or something like that, one user noted. I see Blu-rays on eBay that connect simply through the SATA ports or even USB/etc., and there should be drivers for any major platform to control the drive.

On top of that, Blu-ray playing software is easy to find (at least natively on the Windows platform).

Is there a specific chipset/etc. needed to play/mount Blu-rays (as in movies, etc.), or it's a myth?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no special hardware you need. You're correct that many drives connect via SATA and will just work.

That being said, you computer may not be able to decode and play the blue ray discs.  The discs contain very high bitrate, high resolution videos that require a fairly capable processor to decode.

Answer (score 1):

To watch copy-protected BD movies, a HDCP-capable display pipeline is required. This involves both your graphics card and the display itself. Otherwise, quality may be reduced artificially or playback may fail.

PowerDVD also used to have problems with multi-monitor systems, though that’s hopefully a thing of the past.

Comment: How would it be piracy without an HDCP-capable display?

Comment: To prevent piracy, a HDCP-capable display pipeline is required. <

Comment: You're not making sense. If it's not a problem, why mention it? You make a statement as if you're assuming that, in order to prevent piracy, I need an HDCP-capable standard. So I am enforcing piracy by not using it? Or are you just simply suggesting that it is a means to do so, but the inverse isn't pro-piracy?

Comment: Okay, I realized I've just been trolled -- only a troll would try to be so back and fourth and contradict themselves and keep this show rolling for days and days. Good job, but you haven't been of any help to me.

Comment: @TroughtBrant That attitude won’t get you answers, you know. *You* misunderstood the original statement. So perhaps you trolled yourself? I rewrote the sentence in question.

Comment: I think you should re-establish your answer and make it more clear then. You give too many indefinite sentences and do not exactly make yourself clear (e.g., "YOU NEED THIS, but you can do without it!").

Comment: I don’t see anything “indefinite”. If you’re incapable if understanding, just read the first sentence.

Comment: The first sentence tells me something is required; the third (which should be second) sentence is basically saying, "It's not required," and that's contradictory; quite simple to fathom. As for "indefinite," read this post ... oops; too late. You're basically saying, "To do this, do that; however, that thing I just said isn't required."